# Trouble installing nodejs gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having some trouble installing the nodejs gem. I believe my situation is similar to the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7481391/5), so I followed the instructions and added gem 'nodejs' to the gemfile, but I'm getting the error

```
Could not find gem 'nodejs (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Nodejs isn't a Ruby gem. There are installation instructions on the website: http://nodejs.org/

Comment: Alright thanks! Just starting out so I don't know much about this stuff yet, but I'm learning.

Comment: End up figuring out the problem, just in case others look at this question. I was using netbeans and it had the settings on JRuby as my ruby platform when I'm using version 1.9.2. After I deleted the project and started again it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually no [**nodejs** gem](http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=nodejs) in the RubyGems repository.

The error is just echoing that it can't find a gem with that name.

It's actually just an external binary, that as [Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328095/trouble-installing-nodejs-gem#comment23384276_16328095) mentioned, can be installed using the recommendations from [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/).

Answer (score 3):

The gem is called node: `gem install node`

Comment: It doesn't exist anymore